# Can I open my Delphi 2007 project in Visual Studio (or other IDEs)?

Tags: delphi, ide

I have a big Delphi 2007 project, and the Delphi IDE is slow and unstable even I install [DelphiSpeedUP](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/delphispeedup/), FixIDE Pack.

The IDE freezes for a few seconds when first loading the project (300K lines of code). The Type Library Editor is very inefficient when I want to add a new method/property because it has around 1000 APIs and it kinda freezes for ten seconds in the Type Library Editor.

But the Delphi Compiler is good and I am happy with that, just the IDE has many issues. The Visual Studio 2010/2012 is very good and stable.

Just wondering if it is possible to code in Delphi in the Visual Studio, a basic syntax highlighting, debugger is OK.

Comment: No. Delphi is not one of the languages that is supported in Visual Studio. 300K lines of code is not large at all; I routinely work on projects 30 times larger than that, so if you're having those sorts of issues it's not the IDE.

Comment: i have a COM object that has 1000 methods, and the type library editor is very very slow!

Comment: Sorry. "I have something that makes something slow" is not something we can help with here, because we don't know what that "something" is you have. As I said, Delphi is not one of the languages supported in Visual Studio. Delphi (the language and IDE) are proprietary. You can always either try to switch to Lazarus (good luck with that and type libraries) or switch to using Oxygene or C#.

Comment: Modern Delphi IDEs use text-based RIDL files for Type Libraries. You can edit those in any text editor, and then use Delphi to compile them. You could even load the edited RIDL into the TypeLibrary editor to refresh your code implementation.  Performance issues should be reported to QualityCentral.

Comment: yes, i know RIDLs are text-based... but it is a D2007 project which uses binary *.tlb files

Comment: 1000 methods?!!! What were you thinking of?!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  Yes. what is wrong with too many methods?

Comment: Your component is unmaintainable. All methods glooped into a single do it all class.

Comment: There are other classes as well, not just one

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible.

Visual Studio not work with pascal lang.

You can use np++ for simple syntax highlighting and compile with command lines in DCC32.exe.

and the docs in [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/DCC32.EXE,_the_Delphi_Command_Line_Compiler).

and for Debug use [ollydb](http://ollydbg.de/).

and I'll not suggest it.

and I think the likely pascal IDE to Delphi is [Lazarus](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/) but it can't compile your Delphi source code directly.

and I'll not suggest it too.

I think use the Delphi with fix and speedup patches.

Comment: NP++ doesn't have a type library editor or visual designer, and it's not an IDE. It's a text editor.

Comment: The only proper answer here is "No.", which clearly isn't going to be meaningful. Adding nonsense about other things that have nothing to do with the question asked simply creates noise and clutter. NP++ is not an IDE, which is **specifically** what the question asks, and the complaint is **specifically** about the type library editor, which neither NP++ or Lazarus supports. Therefore the only part of your entire answer that has any meaning is "It is not possible".

Comment: That's not 3 ways. It's 3 things that have nothing to do with the question. It's like the question asking "How do I fix my car?" and you answered "Well, I fix my typewriter by doing this and this and this", **none of which** have to do with **fixing a car**. "Can I use Visual Studio for a Delphi project, because the type library editor is slow", and you answer with 3 things that **don't edit type libraries at all**.